# Missing ROS_format.xml

Tags: eclipse

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I was setting up Eclipse on a fresh Ubuntu install and forgot to save my copy of ROS_format.xml (the C++ auto-formatting for ROS). I went on the site to pull a new copy down (http://www.ros.org/wiki/IDEs) but the link to the XML file seems to be broken. Anyone know where I can get a copy of the XML file?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/11883/missing-ros_format.xml/) by [rtoris288](https://answers.ros.org/users/982/rtoris288/) on ROS Answers with karma: 1173 on 2011-11-10

Post score: 3

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Thanks we're working on it.  There appears to have been a regression in the attachment macro on the wiki.  You can still get it directly from the wiki attachment with the full url http://www.ros.org/wiki/IDEs?action=AttachFile&do=get&target=ROS_format.xml

---

Originally posted by [tfoote](https://answers.ros.org/users/3/tfoote/) with karma: 58457 on 2011-11-10

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 2

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Boris](https://answers.ros.org/users/2873/boris/) on 2012-09-19**:
Link is still (or again) broken. The difference with provided here is the parameter "do=view" instead of "do=get".

Answer (score 0):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

[Here](http://pastebin.com/dCFvmTbc) is a copy of it until someone can get the link fixed.

---

Originally posted by [DimitriProsser](https://answers.ros.org/users/635/dimitriprosser/) with karma: 11163 on 2011-11-10

This answer was **NOT ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 2